# How to test Gitlab-ci Docker + Spring Boot + Testcontainers + Wkhtmltopdf

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, wkhtmltopdf, gitlab-ci-runner, testcontainers

My question is regarding following problem:

1. I want to test the setup of my Wkhtmltopdf service structure
2. Therfore I want to use Gitlab-ci + Docker and Gitlab-Runners
3. The server framework I am using is Spring boot
4. I also have another Docker container which is also running a small web service making it accessible via REST to generate PDF files from urls.
5. For testing I want to use Testcontainers + DockerComposeContainer which is using a compose file defining my test database service and the PDF service.

My problem is the following:
I don't know which host to use for the url the PDF service is going to use for accessing the website on the spring boot service while running the test.

It perfectly works for the spring server to access database and and the PDF service. But I cannot make the PDF service request the provided web url for generating the PDF itself.

I've tried several approaches recommended on the web, like

```
Testcontainers.exposeHostPort
```

Domains

```
host.testcontainers.internal
```

And so on. Running the tests on my local machine don't seem to have any problems, since also docker default ips work as expected.

Please help, I cannot sleep, but I'll try now and I am willing to provide even more information when I'm back up again and at the computer.